# Placing blob half outside html document

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a landing page with some SVGs blobs that are meant to be on the edges of the webpage, half-inside, half-outside. The problem happens when adjusting the blobs for mobile dimensions, the blobs positioned on the right side are generating a lot of white space and thus right-scrolling. I'd like to 'cut' the blob right at the right edge of the screen.

I'm using Bootstrap 5 for this project.

Intended result:

[image: This is the intended result]

Actual result:

[image: Aaand this is it's going.]

Already tried adding `overflow-x: hidden;` and `max-width: 100%;` and its variations.

**Demo:**

```css
  /* CSS class for the blob: */

.cssloco {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 10%;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
}


/* CSS blob class for mobile: */

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .cssloco {
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 40%;
    top: 150%;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="d-flex container mt-15 justify-content-between">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-8 col-md-6 col-sm-8 order-0 order-lg-0 order-sm-0 animacion mensaje-responsive">
      <h1 class="text-start fw-bold">Estás a un mensaje de distancia.</h1>
      <p class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Olvidate de volver a entrar a varios sitios web para conseguir información. <span class="fw-bold">Aerobot</span> te proporciona la forma de tener todo en un mismo lugar, haciendo que tu operación sea <span class="fw-bold">más rápida y más segura, 100% gratis. ✈️ </span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex col col-md-6  order-1 order-sm-1 justify-content-center">

      <div class="svg-blob cssloco">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150%" id="blobSvg">
              <g transform="translate(151.32916831970215, 3.4678802490234375)">
                <defs>
                  <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(76, 161, 175);"></stop>
                    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(196, 224, 229);"></stop>
                  </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <path class="blob" d="M479.79863,286.0103Q472.04119,322.0206,452.55149,352.53089Q433.06179,383.04119,405.37643,404.81464Q377.69107,426.5881,351.37643,453.89702Q325.06179,481.20595,287.53089,468.08238Q250,454.95881,217.0103,453.44851Q184.0206,451.93821,151.9794,441.03089Q119.93821,430.12357,88.91762,409.59268Q57.89702,389.06179,52.17506,352.45881Q46.45309,315.85583,25.64417,282.92792Q4.83524,250,12.26316,212.44851Q19.69107,174.89702,53.56179,153.61327Q87.4325,132.32952,103.80893,101.78833Q120.18536,71.24714,149.05149,49.4897Q177.91762,27.73226,213.95881,30.73226Q250,33.73226,285.07208,34.14988Q320.14417,34.5675,351.69565,50.60869Q383.24714,66.64988,407.42792,92.46911Q431.60869,118.28833,436.97483,152.74714Q442.34096,187.20595,464.94851,218.60298Q487.55607,250,479.79863,286.0103Z" fill="url(#gradient)"></path>
              </g>
            </svg>
      </div>

      <img src="svg/chat1.svg" alt="" class="imagen-reporte animacion">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I looks as though the blob is a visual clue/decoration rather than holding essential meaning. Semantically therefore it would be better to have it as a background-image. Background images can be positioned and sized without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not place a blob as a part of the grid. Make it position: absolute and right: -50%. And fix your SVG. It should not have paddings around  the blob. Take a look on my snippet in full screen, your blob do not shows when it's small.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
#mycont1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cssloco {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  right: -50%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}
.cssloco svg {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mycont1" class="d-flex container mt-15 justify-content-between">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 col-md-6 col-sm-8 order-0 order-lg-0 order-sm-0 animacion mensaje-responsive">
            <h1 class="text-start fw-bold">Estás a un mensaje de distancia.</h1>
            <p class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Olvidate de volver a entrar a varios sitios web para conseguir información. <span class="fw-bold">Aerobot</span> te proporciona la forma de tener todo en un mismo lugar, haciendo que tu operación sea <span class="fw-bold">más rápida y más segura, 100% gratis. ✈️ </span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-blob cssloco">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150%" id="blobSvg">
            <g transform="translate(151.32916831970215, 3.4678802490234375)">
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(76, 161, 175);"></stop>
                    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(196, 224, 229);"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path class="blob" d="M479.79863,286.0103Q472.04119,322.0206,452.55149,352.53089Q433.06179,383.04119,405.37643,404.81464Q377.69107,426.5881,351.37643,453.89702Q325.06179,481.20595,287.53089,468.08238Q250,454.95881,217.0103,453.44851Q184.0206,451.93821,151.9794,441.03089Q119.93821,430.12357,88.91762,409.59268Q57.89702,389.06179,52.17506,352.45881Q46.45309,315.85583,25.64417,282.92792Q4.83524,250,12.26316,212.44851Q19.69107,174.89702,53.56179,153.61327Q87.4325,132.32952,103.80893,101.78833Q120.18536,71.24714,149.05149,49.4897Q177.91762,27.73226,213.95881,30.73226Q250,33.73226,285.07208,34.14988Q320.14417,34.5675,351.69565,50.60869Q383.24714,66.64988,407.42792,92.46911Q431.60869,118.28833,436.97483,152.74714Q442.34096,187.20595,464.94851,218.60298Q487.55607,250,479.79863,286.0103Z" fill="url(#gradient)"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two main way of doing it:

First one is to keep the element in your container but setting the "overflow: hidden" on the container. What you are doing here is to hide the overflow of the image, meaning you try to hide what's overflowing **from** the image.

Second one is to hide the image on mobile and use background image instead, it will be easier as you won't have to handle overflow